# Как находиться онлайн на сайте

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Мне нужно поддерживать онлайн на одном сайте. Пока я решил это сделать таким образом, через селениум:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
```

Но как я понял - данный способ не работает, какие есть еще способы находиться на сайте 24/7?

Comment: нужно переходить по ссылкам на нем

Comment: а как по-вашему вообще можно находиться на сайте постоянно онлайн? как по-вашему сайт "понимает" что вы онлайн?

Answer (score 0):

Сайт понимает, что вы находитесь онлайн, опираясь на ваши действия на нём. Попробуйте зациклить переход по ссылкам на сайте. Условно:

```
import time 
# ...
while True:
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.get(f"{url}/username/")
    time.sleep(10)
    # ...
    time.sleep(10)
```

И вынести это дело, скажем, в отдельный поток, если у вас будут параллельно выполняться ещё строчки кода